# Android using Fragment instead of activity for a library

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design

I am using this library [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/krishnakapil/MaterialSeachView) in my app for implementing Gmail like search view. The library has provided the implementation details using an Activity. I tried the code inside a fragment, making the necessary changes.

To implement it we do something like this from an activity:

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

But, I am using a fragment instead so what I do is:

```
searchView = (MaterialSearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

Everything works fine except the VoiceSearch. The library implements voice search using the following code:

```
private void onVoiceClicked() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak an item name or number");    // user hint
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);    // setting recognition model, optimized for short phrases – search queries
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);    // quantity of results we want to receive
    if (mContext instanceof Activity) {
        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VOICE);
    }
```

How can I make this work? `mContext` in the above code is set inside the constructor as:

```
public MaterialSearchView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}
```

How can I make it work from a fragment? Code for the [library](https://github.com/krishnakapil/MaterialSeachView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/search/material/library/MaterialSearchView.java#L217)

Comment: What, exactly, is not working?

Comment: It doesn't start the activity for handling voice actions, inside onVoiceClicked()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mContext` might not be an `Activity`.

Try using this logic (copied from [MediaRouteButton.getActivity()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteButton.java#MediaRouteButton.getActivity%28%29)) to get the `Activity`.

```
Activity getActivity() {
    Context context = getContext();
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity)context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Edited the library's code and now it works. Thanks !